# CURLOPT_USERAGENT: Mozilla/5.0 vs Googlebot 2.1 - Is one faster?

Tags: http, curl, user-agent

Is there any difference in performance when using Googlebot vs Mozilla as the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`? I'm hypothesizing that some pages might output simpler HTML when Googlebot is the useragent, but I don't really know.

Comment: Since you aren't writing GoogleBot and you aren't writing Mozilla, don't claim to. Your user agent header should name the user agent you are writing. Don't masquerade as something you are not.

Comment: What would I use as my user agent then? The URL of my website? I don't mean to be ignorant about this stuff, I'm kind of a newbie and from looking at CURL examples most either use GoogleBot or Mozilla.

Comment: The usual convention is to use whatever name you have given it, along with a URL to a page about it or an email address that people can use to get in touch if there is a problem with it.

Comment: We could use some more information on what your application/website is doing in order to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a user agent won't make your cURL call faster. In fact, in some servers, they intend to block suspicious User Agent. Therefore, just use the default user agent is fine.